# Close all running apps on single UIButton touch?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I wana close all the application runing in the background by single button click. Is this possible? I read all the related post.They all describe about the single application but i want to close all the running apps.I know that apple doesn't allow this.But Is there any private api for this? Please help me.Help would be appricieted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, push Power button and hold it for 4 seconds. This will close all running apps.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev :- hehehe.. i haven't done that... but will it only closes all running app or it switches the phone also??? :P

Comment: Thanks man but i wana do it through xcode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think So we can do anything like this as You want to do that from some app which is having its own Address Space i.e. sandBox. Means Every App is having its own Address Space which Other App Cannot Access it, as it will result in Crash.

So, sorry to say but we Cannot up to my Knowledge... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible but Even if you do something like this your app is for sure be rejected from uploading on app store, this will be a virus for iphone,

Comment: I know my app will be rejected on app store.But Is there any way to do this?

Comment: dude this would be a negative aspect of suggestion, i don't know right now, but even if i had such knowledge i wouldn't have told you, kindly make your app friendly, it should not hurt other apps functionality,

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stop all running apps by any means, and there is no way to do this programmatically other than jail breaking your device and hacking something together.

But in the end it makes no sense at all, see: http://speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html